# How to call a function only once in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, static

I would like to call a recursive function only once. I tried it as we do for a static variable but it is throwing an error. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Say I have function `recur(int j)`:

```
void recur(int x){
    if(x==0)
        return;
    //want x to be xth fibnocci number,but only at initialization.
    x=fib(x);
    cout<<x<<" ";
    recur(x-1);
}
```

The output of `recur(5)` should be `{5,4,3,2,1}` and not `{5,3,1}`. *I want to do it inside the function only.*

Comment: Why not pass `fib(x)` into the function like `recur(fib(x))`? This is where the starting value of that variable should exist

Comment: Comment out this line `x=fib(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to have a variable start a certain way in function (whether it be recursive or not), you should handle this through the function arguments. The function is already set up to have an initialization stage.

Example:

```
void recur(int x){
    if(x==0)
        return;
    cout<<x<<" ";
    recur(x-1);
}

int main() {
    recur(fib(x));
    return 0;
 }
```